# webpack/vue/nuxt - Map import if file exists (overwrite)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, loader

In my current project I am trying to implement the following:

Let's assume the following file structure:

```
/src/
/src/components/MyComponent.vue
/src/overwrites/components/MyComponent.vue
```

(in any *.vue file):
`import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'.`

This import should, if the same file exists in the parallel existing directory "overwrites", import it instead of the one from /src/components/.

To benefit from hot reloading etc, I want to solve this via webpack.

However, how to extend the vue-loader or get in front of it I haven't figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with a custom webpack resolver. Similar to this one:
https://github.com/hollandThomas/webpack-custom-resolver/blob/master/StyleResolverPlugin.js

However, I check for ".vue" instead of ".js" and then I substitute the path instead of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require.context` to crawl directory for components without a `webpack` or `vue-loader` involved.

For instance you have structure:

```
.src
+-- components
|   +-- MyComponent.vue
+-- overwrites
|  +-- components
|  |   +-- MyComponent.vue
```

You will put `index.js` file in every `components` folder with content:

```js
const requireModule = require.context('./', false, /\.vue$/)
requireModule.keys().forEach(fileName => {
    if (fileName === './index.js') return;
    const moduleName = pascalCase(
        fileName.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, '')
    );
    components[moduleName] = requireModule(fileName)
});
export default components;
```

Then you will be able to import those `index.js` files in root component file like:

```
import components from './components/index.js';
export default {
    components: components,
    // ...
}
```

It will load all `vue` files from `components` directory. It will solve the issue of hot reloading.

Though, you will have to manage loading of duplicated components on your own, probably with `Object.assing` like:

```
import components from './components/index.js';
import {components as overwrites} from './overwrites/components/index.js';
export default {
    components: Object.assign({}, components, overwrites),
    // ...
}
```

Duplicated components will be substituted.

Comment: Sounds nice, but I want to solve it with webpack.

I don't want to manage it myself in one file. The existence of the file should be enough to overwrite it.